# How to create a difference map between two matplotlib hexbin maps?

Tags: python, matplotlib, hex, difference, bins

I encountered a problem on creating a difference map between two `matplotlib.pyplot` `hexbin` plots, which means to get the value differences of each corresponding `hexbin` first and then create a difference `hexbin` map.

To give a simple example of my problem here, say the value of one `hexbin` in Map 1 is 3 and the value of the corresponding `hexbin` in Map 2 is 2, what I would like to do is to get the difference 3 – 2 = 1 first and then plot it in a new hexbin map, i.e. a difference map, at the same positions as Map 1 and Map 2.

My input codes and output plots are as follows. Could anyone please give me a solution to this problem?

Thanks for your time!

```
In [1]: plt.hexbin(lon_origin_df, lat_origin_df)
Out[1]: <matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection at 0x13ff40610>
```

[image]

```
In [2]: plt.hexbin(lon_termination_df, lat_termination_df)
Out[2]: <matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection at 0x13fff49d0>
```

[image]

Comment: Is [rectangular histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) out of the question? `hexbin`'s binning logic is not detachable from the creation of a polygon collection in the current code.

Comment: The answer below works. Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to get the values from a `h=hexbin()` using `h.get_values()`, and set the values using `h.set_values()`, so you could create a new `hexbin` and set its values to the difference between the other two. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

x  = np.random.random(200)
y1 = np.random.random(200)
y2 = np.random.random(200)

pl.figure()
pl.subplot(131)
h1=pl.hexbin(x, y1, gridsize=3, vmin=0, vmax=40, cmap=pl.cm.RdBu_r)
pl.colorbar()

pl.subplot(132)
h2=pl.hexbin(x, y2, gridsize=3, vmin=0, vmax=40, cmap=pl.cm.RdBu_r)
pl.colorbar()

pl.subplot(133)
# Create dummy hexbin using whatever data..:
h3=pl.hexbin(x, y2, gridsize=3, vmin=-10, vmax=10, cmap=pl.cm.RdBu_r)
h3.set_array(h1.get_array()-h2.get_array())
pl.colorbar()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! It does helps me a lot!